# Does a MySQL, PHP, JSON framework exist?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest

I'd like to query a MySQL database via a RESTful service with the middleware being PHP. I'd like the output to be JSON. I'm a beginner in those areas. Are there any frameworks or scripts that can do this without requiring you to be an expert?  I don't have a problem stringing a few scripts together if they can work.

Or, if it can be done much simpler without using REST (i.e. query parameters), that's fine.

In the end, I want to have an iPhone app fetch this data and have it returned via JSON.  No javascript will be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a MySQL result set to JSON easily: http://phpclasses.nlared.com/browse/package/3195.html

For a RESTful interface, basically any hosted PHP script can function as a REST interface for your application.

Comment: I took a look at it. In the example.php, he has require("dbcon.php");. I'm not sure what goes in dbcon.php. He also writes the query in example.php, which isn't what I want. I'd like to use something like REST to build the query.

Comment: dbconf is most likely referring to the mysql_connect function (which the author put into a seperate file, but could be inline'd pretty easily. This one-liner should do the trick: @mysql_connect ($servername,$dbuser,$dbpassword);  ... fill in the parameters.

Comment: Perfect. I have it successfully querying the DB now.  How do I build my queries via the URL (in a RESTful manner if possible)?  I'm still using the hard coded SELECT in the example.php.

Comment: The basic idea is to build your query using the URL path, for example: myapp.com/houses/california/ This would yield all houses available for sale in California.

You can do this manually by looking at $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in any PHP script or let a framework such as Code Igniter handle this for your.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this project: http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/

> On this site you will find a RESTful
>   interface (written in PHP) to a
>   database (a MySQL database, but that's
>   not important). Below you will find a
>   interactive tutorial that will get you
>   accessing, adding and deleting rows
>   from our database via our Javascript
>   powered REST browser.

Comment: Yes - I actually sent you an email because it just errors out on me. "error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty" in index.php is what it says.  When I view source, I see my database tables are there.  However, the service doesn't output JSON.

Comment: Ah yes - you could wrap the responses with an XML to JSON conversion - perhaps with http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/   . As for the error message, it'd be best to seek help with the project administrators or the project forms : http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprestsql/support

Answer (score 0):

The PHP shouldn't necessarily be your middleware in your situation, you'll have to build your "RESTful" service somehow, whether it be with PHP or any other language. You don't have to be an expert, but I think CakePHP has some of these capabilities.

Maybe explain in more detail what you want to do.

**Update**

Try this out:
http://techno-geeks.org/2009/08/easy-json-with-cakephp-and-jquery/

Not only is CakePHP easy to install and use, it's also easy to extend.

Comment: Can't use JQuery.  This is going to go onto an iPhone.  I've updated the OP.

Comment: I love cakePHP but I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner. There is defiantly a learning curve involved.